# How to apply existing migrations for ApplicationDbContext in Release build of ASP.NET Core web application using SQLite

Tags: sqlite, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations, dotnet-cli

I am unable to apply existing migrations for ApplicationDbContext on the Release build of my ASP.NET Core web application using SQLite database. As a result, I have to copy over my sqlite .db file from Debug build (which I am able to apply migrations) to the Release build just so I can deploy it on my Ubuntu Server. Either that, or I have to call `app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();` in the `public void Configure()` method inside `Startup.cs` for Production environment, which is not recommended.

To recreate the issue, create an ASP.NET Core Web Application (.NET Core) in Visual Studio with Individual User Accounts Authentication. I called my project **Hevn**.

Then, update `project.json` to use SQLite instead of SQL Server.

```
// Change from this
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.0.1",
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design": {
  "version": "1.0.1",
  "type": "build"
},

// to this
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite": "1.0.1",
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite.Design": {
  "version": "1.0.1",
  "type": "build"
},
```

Then, update `Startup.cs` to use SQLite instead of SQL Server:

```
// Change from this
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
  options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

// to this
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
  options.UseSqlite(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

Then, open `appsettings.json` and change DefaultConnection to use SQLite database. (I named mine **Hevn.db**):

```
// Change DefaultConnection to use SQLite database called Hevn.db
"ConnectionStrings": {
  "DefaultConnection": "Data Source=./Hevn.db"
},
```

Then open Command Prompt and apply migrations by navigating to the project and running `dotnet ef database update`

```
cd "%USERPROFILE%/Documents/Visual Studio 2015/Projects/Hevn/src/Hevn"
dotnet ef database update
dotnet run
```

This creates `bin/Debug/netcoreapp1.0` folder and inside that folder resides `Hevn.db` sqlite database file. When I browse the sqlite file, I can see that the tables necessary for authentication have been created (i.e. `AspNetUsers` table).

However, I am unable to do this for the release build. I can run `dotnet build -c Release` to build a Release version of my app under `bin/Release/netcoreapp1.0`. I can also run `dotnet run -c Release` to run the Release version of my app. Running the Release version will create `Hevn.db` sqlite file under `bin/Release/netcoreapp1.0`, but browsing the sqlite file shows that no table has been created.

At this point, my only option is to copy the `Hevn.db` file from Debug into Release build.

I also tried `dotnet ef database update -e Production`, but that still creates `Hevn.db` under Debug build.

When I run my ASP.NET Core web app in Debug mode before applying migration, I get the following screen when I attempt to Register/Login. I can simply click Apply Migrations or run `dotnet ef database update` to apply migrations and Registration/Login works using SQLite.
[image: Able to apply migration in Debug mode]

But when I run my ASP.NET Core web app in Release mode, I get the following screen when I attempt to Register/Login. There is no way I can apply migrations to the Release build.
[image: Unable to apply migration in Release mode]

Is it possible to apply migrations on Release build of ASP.NET Core web app? Or do I have to resort to copying over database migrated sqlite file from Debug to Release?

Answer (score 0):

`dotnet ef database update` is the correct command. However by default it runs under debug configuration. -e changes the Environment (i.e. affects code like env.IsDevelopment()) It won't make it run under Release. -c before database should do that. Please see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dotnet

Another alternative is having different connectionstrings based on the environment and then you could use -e to control which environment to use.

Comment: I already saw https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dotnet and the `dotnet ef database update` command doesn't have a `-c` before database. The `-c` flag is used at the end of the command to specify the context, but since I'm just using the default context, I leave it out. If I do `dotnet ef database update -c Release`, I receive error `No DbContext named 'Release' was found.`

Comment: Also, I just tried your suggestion `dotnet ef -c Release database update` and received an error `Unrecognized option '-c'`. I'm still inclined to believe that there is no way to apply migrations to the Release build for SQLite dbs in EF Core.

Answer (score 0):

this command created my sqlite database in the release folder:

```
dotnet ef database update --configuration release
```

but then i'm using the new msbuild .csproj rather than project.json and latest SDK.  Not sure if that might be affecting you?

Comment: I tried `dotnet ef database update --configuration release` and received the error `Unrecognized option '--configuration'`. I'm using dotnet version 1.0.0-preview2-003131, which still uses project.json. Can you tell me what version you are running (`dotnet --version`)?

Comment: 1.0.0-preview4-004233.  This does mean another phase of learning for you though if you choose that option.  I was hoping it would fix it for you in your version too.

Comment: was it perhaps called something different in a previous version? does this give you any clues?  `dotnet ef database update --help`

Comment: Thanks. I just decided to stick with 1.0.0.-preview2-1-003177 since that is the latest release version from https://www.microsoft.com/net/core. I'm well aware of MS move from project.json to csproj and MSBuild. I'll wait until Preview 4 is stable and MS releases not only CLI tools, but also Visual Studio and VS Code tooling as well.

Comment: `dotnet ef database update --help` shows no option called `--configuration`. Maybe its new for Preview 4 release.

Comment: ah.  shame.  Depending on your scenario, a workaround for you until the upgrade might be to use `context.Database.Migrate();` in your project startup.cs?  It has worked for me in project.json scenarios.